# Rockets and fluid mechanics question (not technical)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi I am just wondering what kind of maths goes into rockets and fluid mechanics.
I understand there is variable mass system.

But I guess they must also consider the change in gravity and air resistance depending on height and on speed. 
This just seems like a lot of variables and am wondering how mathematicians would model this?  Would it be ODES, PDE'S for example and what other maths would be involved?
Also what does fluid mechanics entail? I assume this would be of equal importance to anyone in making rockets, cars, missiles ext and am wondering what kind of maths goes into it.

At undergraduate level, which topics complement classical mechanics/dynamics relativity and fluid dynamics best?
At A-level it was all just simple differential equations and integrals.
Im wondering whether it would need an understanding of multivariate calculus at uni .(including partial derivatives , triple integrals, contour integration, vector fields, stokes and greens theorem and whatever else i really dunno haha im not an undergrad just yet.

Also would this require a solid understanding of multivariate analysis (i.e of 2 variables?)
Im also just wondering what a surface integral would be useful for in general. I know that a line integral could be considered as work done by a particle going from A to B but am not sure about for 3d.
would complex analysis be useful?

So basically what would be the order of these prerequisites be in terms of learning? I guess real analysis--> multivariate analysis--> diff, int, and then i have no idea
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I studied (and worked for a while in ) aerospace engineering.  Yes, the modeling of flights (and fluid mechanics in general) does involve a lot of physics to be modeled.  At some coarser levels of modeling, and restricting to some regimes, ODEs will do and one can think of a variable-mass system etc, but for more careful modeling of the physics, PDEs are a mainstay in this field.

Apart from the things you mentioned, there is a also fluid-structure interaction ( the solid mechanics in the craft is described by PDEs, the flow outside is described by different PDEs and the two interact through the boundary ).  The aircraft problem called Flutter is a famous example of fluid-structure interaction leading to failure.

As you mentioned, in the range of regimes to be considered, gravity is not constant anymore and nor is the fluid unchanging.  In the higher reaches of the atmosphere, it's not [continuum mechanics anymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knudsen_number) at all as the mean free path of the molecules becomes large. Then there is celestial mechanics after leaving the atmosphere...

Many things to keep track of, but I wouldn't say it's hard. Although there is plenty of math to deal with, I'd say there's nothing in the field that is intuition-bending.

Coming back to what you need to know to be practictioner - all of the math that you mentioned.  Calculus of one and many variables, ODEs, PDEs, mechanics in general - you need all this, but with experience, they will all become natural. Stokes and Green's - will be useful in understanding proofs of some results in school or for proving them, but I don't recall having used them explicitly at work.